# How does .waypoint work?

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery-waypoints

If a have a code like this

```
var waypoint = new Waypoint({
  element:document.getElementsByClassName  ('waypoint'),
  handler: function(direction) {
    console.log('Scrolled to waypoint!')
  }
});
```

And I have 10 elements that have 'waypoint' class,how does waypoint plugin control if those elements are visible in viewport?Does it control all div's offsets every time onscroll event is triggered?

Comment: http://imakewebthings.com/waypoints/guides/getting-started/ look here for detail and examples

Answer (score 0):

When you scroll to `element` it calls `handler`. Waypoints does not control the display or visibility of Elements. You can set an `offset` trigger point with the `options` Object. You can use the function you assign to `handler` to program changes within. Waypoints seems like a poor choice for naming this API.

Comment: What does it mean that "it calls handler"?Who calls handler?

Comment: Behind the scenes there's a scroll Event firing and when you scroll to `element` it executes the function assigned to `handler`.

Comment: Ok,so Scroll eent firing means that every time onscroll event is fired the API controls element's offset to see if it is in viewport area.What does it happen if we have more element to control?

Comment: It should loop over the Elements if they are a collection, but I never tested it, and documentation does not specify. It will definitely work If you use the jQuery way. See http://imakewebthings.com/waypoints/api/waypoint/ for details. You can always make a `new Waypoint()` for a single waypoint. If using jQuery it's like `$('.waypoint').waypoint({handler:function(){/* change DOM here */}});`

Comment: Ok,what type of test could we do to see if it loops over the elements?

Comment: Without using jQuery, it would fire where every HTML `class='waypoint'` is, as you scroll down the page. If it does not and you have multiple `class='waypoint'`s, you'll have to run a loop.